# I have a problem with my monitor mode for wireless

Tags: wireless, networking

I am using Ubuntu 12.04. I need to shut down monitor mode for WiFi, but when I try to do that it always come up like this:

```
savko@savko-1015CX:~$ airmon-ng stop wlan0
airmon-ng: command not found
```

Now, I know this is the right command, but I don't know why it's not working. Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

If it used to work but doesn't now, try the following command in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install aircrack-ng
```

thiswill tell you if the latest version is installed, or install it if it not found.

Comment: Package aircrack-ng is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  iw NOW WHAT? :)

Comment: it's not available on LTS and LTS still has the -1 channel bug.  you need to patch your wireless stack to have the negative one channel issue fixed, add the pi-rho repo, install aircrack, and move forward or use scapy scripts with an awareness of what they do.

Comment: i just downloaded linux-source just to patch the wireless driver... just saying.  90 megs is excessive.

Comment: Wait, i'm not that good like you. Is it a problem for you to write me down exactly what i need to type in TERMINAL to install aircrack. I would apreciate that. Thanks.

Comment: Dl-ng too, 67megs. Let's see what wil happen. I'm new to Linux so i hope i will not make a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

To stop an interface form monitor mode you can use `sudo iwconfig [interface] mode managed`. It sets the interface to client mode.

As you can set the interface into monitor mode by the command `sudo iwconfig [interface] mode monitor`. Of course just a few wireless cards support monitor mode by default.

To know more commands about Linux wireless go [here](http://wirelessdefence.org/Contents/LinuxWirelessCommands.htm).